# Question about C++ folder structure for header file

Tags: c++

I'm quite new in C++ after few years in Java and eclipse, I got little bit confusing using code::blocks, no autogenerate setter/getter and also implement interface :D.

I wanna ask about code structure in code::blocks, I create new console application, my header will be put to Headers/include folder called Employee.h, then .cpp will be put to src folder.
Now I create main class (I put outside of src folder) who will call the header, I just append the include code like this :

```
#include "Employee.h"
```

sure then the errors appeared after compiling:
error : Employee.h: No such file or directory.

how to link the header to the main class properly?

this is my folder structure :

[image]

updated :
It works, my include folder needs to be added on build options.
[image]

Really thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add your include directory to your compiler's include path. This is going to be compiler-specific.  e.g., if your structure is:

```
code
code/src
code/include
```

and you're running g++ from a terminal in the 'code' directory, you'd need to run (assuming your .cpp is Employee.cpp):

```
g++ -Iinclude src/Employee.cpp
```

I suspect you're running some sort of IDE, though: if so, do a search in its help for "include path" and it should tell you how to set it up correctly.

Comment: yeahhhh...it works, I need to add my "include" folder on build options. The capture is attached above.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include your `employee.h` you must `#include "employee.h"` not `Employee.h`. Those are two different files.

Comment: Probable the location of the file also needs to be validated.

Comment: ups sorry for my wrong typed, I mean I have Employee.h not employee.h, I really sure this issue is about wrong addressing of my header.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be adding include paths to your build options for header files that are actually *part* of your project.  It didn't find the header file from the EmployeeTest.cpp because you didn't use the full relative path.

You need:

```
#include "include/Employee.h"
```

You should only be adding include paths to your compiler for additional libraries that aren't added to the typical /usr/local/include or /usr/include directories.

Comment: What happens when Employee.h gets moved from folder include into some other folder, maybe.. "company" for instance?  In this example he/she should add the include path to the build options, albeit, this structure is not good.  Instead of Headers/Include/Employee.. Just setup your project to be Headers/...(all your header files)  @Mr. K